# how can I get details from restful api django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am pretty new with restful Django, but I am not new with Django framework at all, but I want to create an endpoint where I can grab customers by id e.g. `detail/<id>` `customers/` to grab all

```
serializers.py

class CustomersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'



views.py

class CustomerViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                      viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """
    get all 
    """
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomersSerializer

 urls.py

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'customer', CustomerViewSet) # get all 
router.register(r'detail', DetailViewSet) # detail/<id>
```

```
class DetailViewSet(...):
   ????
```

Comment: use `ModelViewSet`, which compatible for CRUD operations

Comment: in code , how would it be for retrieve by id?

Comment: [DRF `ModelViewSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

views.py :

```
from rest_framework import generics

class CustomerDetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    """
    get all 
    """
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomersSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
```

urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (CustomerDetailAPIView)

urlpatterns = [

    path('customer_detail/<int:pk>',CustomerDetailAPIView.as_view()),

]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another ViewSet for retrieve. `viewsets.ViewSet` itself has two methods `list(self, request)` and `retrieve(self, request, pk=None)`